# getting original file name of uploaded file grails

Tags: grails, file-upload

I am getting the uploaded file using request.getFile("file") where "file" is the name of file input element in my gsp file. I am able to parse this file fine but when I try to get the file's original name, I encounter the following error

No signature of method: org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.getOriginalFileName() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getOriginalFilename()

This is my code:

```
def f = request.getFile("file")
def name = f.getOriginalFileName()
```

Why can't I call the getOriginalFileName() method on 'f', I thought request.getFile() returned a MultipartFile object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception shows that it's a capitalization issue on method call `f.getOriginalFileName()` -> `f.getOriginalFilename()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code, which worked for me:

```
def uploadedFileName = request.getFile("file")    
def fileName = uploadedFileName.originalFilename
```